# How to insert empty rows above data header row using sheetjs package in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, sheetjs

Hello everyone please need helo to achieve similar using NODEJS sheetjs package
(**Desired Sheet**):
[image: Desired Sheet]

I want to know how can I insert the few empty rows and then append the sheet.

**Currently my exported data look like this**:
[image: current data]

I tried **sheet_to_aoa and all but didn't work**. The data was overriding the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Your desired format require to handle header, data manually.

Use this to append row to the end of the sheet

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_add_aoa(workSheet, [['', 'Your', 'Desired data']], {
  skipHeader: true, // Won't override headers
  origin: -1, // Add to the end
});
```